# VB Source Folder Question

Tags: vb.net

How can I pick out files using todays date?

I have files that have dates and times in a folder, 08-25-2010-123803654.xml, 08-25-2010-123804441.xml, 08-24-2010-123851240.xml, etc.

I want to pull out just todays entrys and when i put in my code it gives me an error.

My code is:

> SourceFolder = "C:\TEST(DateTime.Now.tostring('MM-dd-yyyy-*')"

Im not sure what Im doing wrong here.

Thanks

MY Code: 
Module Module1

```
Private Property fs As Object
Private Property BaseName As Object
Private Property FullTargetPath As Object

Sub Main()


    Dim xlApp, xlWkb, SourceFolder, TargetFolder, file
    xlApp = CreateObject("excel.application")
    fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Const xlNormal = 1
    SourceFolder = "C:\TEST\" & DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") & "*"
    TargetFolder = "C:\TEST\Excel"

    'Hide Excel
    xlApp.Visible = False

    'Process each file in SourceFolder
    For Each file In fs.GetFolder(SourceFolder).files
        'Open file in SourceFolder
        xlWkb = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(file)
        'Get Filename
        BaseName = fs.getbasename(file)
        'Concatenate full path. Extension will be automatically added by Excel
        FullTargetPath = TargetFolder & "\" & BaseName
        'Save as XLS file into TargetFolder
        xlWkb.SaveAs(FullTargetPath, xlNormal)
        'Close the file after its done
        xlWkb.close()
    Next

    xlWkb = Nothing
    xlApp = Nothing
    fs = Nothing

    MsgBox("Finished. Bout time!")


End Sub
```

End Module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to translate just this portion of your code to hopefully put you on the right track:

```
Dim targetFolder As String = "C:\TEST\Excel"

Dim sourceFolder As String = "C:\TEST"

' Here is where we specify a pattern by which we will find files in '
' sourceFolder. '
Dim searchPattern As String = String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}*.xml", Date.Today)

' This will give us an array with only those files matching the pattern above; '
' that is, only files from today. '
Dim todaysFiles() As String = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder, searchPattern)

For Each file As String In todaysFiles
    ' Excel stuff... '

    Dim fileName As String = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)

    ' Concatenate full path. Extension will be automatically added by Excel. '
    Dim fullTargetPath = Path.Combine(targetFolder, fileName)

    ' More Excel stuff... '
Next
```

Comment: So then sourcefolder should read, 

>SourceFolder = directory
>TargetFolder = "C:\TEST\Excel"

How would searchpattern come into play?

Comment: Yes, that seems to help quite a bit and I understand it now, although I get a new error, I created a private function for directory() and when I run the console app now it says the following: System.NotImplementedException was unhandled
  Message=The method or operation is not implemented.
  Source=ConsoleApplication3

Comment: @gabrielVa: Well, then... can you change the name of your function so it doesn't overlap with a member of `System.IO`? Alternately you could simply resolve the ambiguity by typing out `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles`.

Comment: Thanks Dan, looks like Ive go one final hurdle, i get Illegal characters in path under todaysfiles()

Dim targetfolder As String = "C:\TEST\Excel"
        Dim sourcefolder As String = "C:\TEST"
        Dim Searchpattern As String = String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}-*.xml", Date.Today)
        Dim todaysfiles() As String = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Searchpattern)

TXT Visualizer shows the following though: 08-26-2010-*.xml

Comment: @gabirelVa: Wow, I apologize -- I posted flat-out wrong code. Sorry! Use `Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder, searchPattern)` instead (updated answer).

Comment: Yes!! That worked Dan! The file now pulls form the data source folder as well as the search pattern. Thank you so VERY much Dan!!

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted doesn't actually append todays date to the base path, it creates a static string. Don't you mean:

```
SourceFolder = "C:\TEST\" & DateTime.Now.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy") & "*"
```

Comment: Hey David, 

I tried that but I keep getting an error under the following: 

For Each file In fs.GetFolder(SourceFolder).files

Error is: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A004C (CTL_E_PATHNOTFOUND)